# when update large table it take too much time to update

Tags: query-performance, stored-procedures, execution-plan, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

I work on sql server 2019

when update table `Z2DataCore.parts.SourcingNotMappedParts`  i found slow and long time when update

[estimated execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry99b8Re9)

[actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r11YYOy-q)

Update statement takes 26.5 minute to finish update for count of rows 692488 so How to make Faster .

statment generate slow process as below :

```
UPDATE s 
SET s.PriorityLevel = 'I2'   
FROM Z2DataCore.parts.SourcingNotMappedParts s 
INNER JOIN extractreports.dbo.alldistSuppliersourceid g
    ON g.SourcingNotMappedPartsID = s.SourcingNotMappedPartsID
```

count rows affected for updated will be 692488

table SourcingNotMappedParts that i need to update it have 71 milion rows as general .

table `extractreports.dbo.SourcingNotMappedPartsIDI1` i will get data from it to update is 692488 .

table `extractreports.dbo.SourcingNotMappedPartsIDI1` have only column `SourcingNotMappedPartsID` with `int datatype`

table `extractreports.dbo.SourcingNotMappedPartsIDI1` have only one index as below

```
 CREATE clustered INDEX SourcingNotMappedPartsIDI1_IDX ON extractreports.dbo.SourcingNotMappedPartsIDI1(SourcingNotMappedPartsID)



USE [Z2DataCore]
 GO
 /****** Object:  Table [Parts].[SourcingNotMappedParts]    Script Date: 3/4/2022 12:05:36 AM ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 CREATE TABLE [Parts].[SourcingNotMappedParts](
  [SourcingNotMappedPartsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [SearchPart] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
  [GivenManufacture] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
  [CompanyId] [int] NULL,
  [SourceTypeID] [int] NULL,
  [PartStatus] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
  [StockId] [int] NULL,
  [SourceUrl] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
  [PartId] [int] NULL,
  [GroupID] [int] NULL,
  [PartStatusID] [int] NULL,
  [MatchStatus] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
  [GivenPartNumber_Non] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
  [GivenManufacturer_Non] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
  [signatureID] [int] NULL,
  [VCompanyId] [int] NULL,
  [PriorityLevel] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [NotMappedCode] [int] NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Parts.SourcingNotMappedParts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
  [SourcingNotMappedPartsID] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
    
 GO
 SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    
 GO
 /****** Object:  Index [IDX_MatchStatus_StatusID]    Script Date: 3/4/2022 12:05:37 AM ******/
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_MatchStatus_StatusID] ON [Parts].[SourcingNotMappedParts]
 (
  [PartStatusID] ASC,
  [MatchStatus] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 /****** Object:  Index [IDX_Part_status_ID]    Script Date: 3/4/2022 12:05:37 AM ******/
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Part_status_ID] ON [Parts].[SourcingNotMappedParts]
 (
  [PartStatusID] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    
 GO
 /****** Object:  Index [IDX_SourceURL]    Script Date: 3/4/2022 12:05:37 AM ******/
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_SourceURL] ON [Parts].[SourcingNotMappedParts]
 (
  [SourceUrl] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    
 GO
 /****** Object:  Index [IDX_SourcingNotMappedParts_GroupID_SearchPart]    Script Date: 3/4/2022 12:05:37 AM ******/
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_SourcingNotMappedParts_GroupID_SearchPart] ON [Parts].[SourcingNotMappedParts]
 (
  [GroupID] ASC,
  [SearchPart] ASC
 )
 INCLUDE (  [signatureID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 /****** Object:  Index [IDX_SourcingNotMappedParts_PartId]    Script Date: 3/4/2022 12:05:37 AM ******/
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_SourcingNotMappedParts_PartId] ON [Parts].[SourcingNotMappedParts]
 (
  [PartId] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 /****** Object:  Index [IDX_SourcingNotMappedParts_SignatureID]    Script Date: 3/4/2022 12:05:37 AM ******/
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_SourcingNotMappedParts_SignatureID] ON [Parts].[SourcingNotMappedParts]
 (
  [signatureID] ASC
 )
 INCLUDE (  [PartId]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    
 GO
 /****** Object:  Index [IX_NotMapped_NonalphaPartCompany]    Script Date: 3/4/2022 12:05:37 AM ******/
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NotMapped_NonalphaPartCompany] ON [Parts].[SourcingNotMappedParts]
 (
  [GivenPartNumber_Non] ASC,
  [VCompanyId] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 /****** Object:  Index [IX_NotMapped_NotMappedCode]    Script Date: 3/4/2022 12:05:37 AM ******/
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NotMapped_NotMappedCode] ON [Parts].[SourcingNotMappedParts]
 (
  [NotMappedCode] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    
 GO
 /****** Object:  Index [IX_NotMapped_PriorityLevel]    Script Date: 3/4/2022 12:05:37 AM ******/
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NotMapped_PriorityLevel] ON [Parts].[SourcingNotMappedParts]
 (
  [PriorityLevel] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 /****** Object:  Index [IX_NotMapped_SourceType]    Script Date: 3/4/2022 12:05:37 AM ******/
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NotMapped_SourceType] ON [Parts].[SourcingNotMappedParts]
 (
  [SourceTypeID] ASC,
  [CompanyId] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    
 GO
 /****** Object:  Index [IX_NotMapped_VCompanyId_sourcetypeid]    Script Date: 3/4/2022 12:05:37 AM ******/
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NotMapped_VCompanyId_sourcetypeid] ON [Parts].[SourcingNotMappedParts]
 (
  [VCompanyId] ASC,
  [SourceTypeID] ASC,
  [PriorityLevel] ASC
 )
 INCLUDE (  [GivenPartNumber_Non]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    
 GO
 /****** Object:  Index [IX_SourcingNotMappedParts_VCompanyId]    Script Date: 3/4/2022 12:05:37 AM ******/
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SourcingNotMappedParts_VCompanyId] ON [Parts].[SourcingNotMappedParts]
 (
  [VCompanyId] ASC
 )
 INCLUDE (  [CompanyId],
  [SourceTypeID],
  [StockId],
  [GivenPartNumber_Non],
  [PriorityLevel]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
```

so how to solve issue of slow please?

i checked updated status i found wait type as below :

[image: check wait type status]

so are this related to slow or not related .

Comment: ...Upon further inspection it seems you replaced your `extractreports.dbo.SourcingNotMappedPartsIDI1` with a temp table `#alldistSuppliersourceid` which certainly would result in a different execution plan, given your DDL scripts show an applicable index exists on `extractreports.dbo.SourcingNotMappedPartsIDI1` but that same index does not exist on your temp table. Please either post the correct actual execution plan for when you use the `extractreports.dbo.SourcingNotMappedPartsIDI1` table or let us know if you want further help with optimizing the query for when you use a temp table instead.

Comment: yes you are correct i try to use temp to make it quickly but still take 22 minute to update 500 k so are there are any solution to enhance that please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your updated actual execution plan is also indicating you have no indexes on your `extractreports.dbo.alldistSuppliersourceid` table because it is currently using a Table Scan operation against it.

It should at the minimum have a clustered index. If that clustered index makes sense to be on the field your query is currently joining on `SourcingNotMappedPartsID` (depending on how often you query by that column) then you could create it like so:

```
USE extractreports;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_alldistSuppliersourceid_ ON dbo.alldistSuppliersourceid (SourcingNotMappedPartsID);
```

If `SourcingNotMappedPartsID` is unique in `extractreports.dbo.alldistSuppliersourceid` then you can also specify the `UNIQUE` keyword after the`CREATE` keyword.

Otherwise if another field makes sense to be the clustered index on `extractreports.dbo.alldistSuppliersourceid`, then use the above script, substituting out that column, to create the clustered index and you can create an additional nonclustered index on it instead like so:

```
USE extractreports;

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_alldistSuppliersourceid_ ON dbo.alldistSuppliersourceid (SourcingNotMappedPartsID);
```

Again, using the `UNIQUE` keyword if it's applicable as well.

That one index should at least help your performance to a degree.